# Tensorflow : Get indices of array rows which are zero

Tags: arrays, indexing, tensorflow

For a tensor

```
[[1 2 3 1]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [1 3 5 7]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [3 5 7 8]]
```

how can I get the indices of the 0 rows? I.e. the list [1,3], in Tensorflow?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't really do that in one command like you would with a more advanced library like NumPy.
If you really want to use TF functions I could suggest a few like:

```
x = tf.Variable([
    [1,2,3,1],
    [0,0,0,0],
    [1,3,5,7],
    [0,0,0,0],
    [3,5,7,8]])

y = tf.Variable([0,0,0,0])
condition = tf.equal(x, y)
indices = tf.where(condition)
```

This would result the following:

```
[[1 0]
 [1 1]
 [1 2]
 [1 3]
 [3 0]
 [3 1]
 [3 2]
 [3 3]]
```

Or you could use the following if you just want to get only the zero lines:

```
row_wise_sum = tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(x),1)
select_zero_sum = tf.where(tf.equal(row_wise_sum,0))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    print(sess.run(select_zero_sum))
```

The result being:

```
[[1]
 [3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in an easier way too:

```
    g = tf.Graph()
    with g.as_default():
       a = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[3, 4])
       b = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[1, 4])

       res = tf.not_equal(a, b)
       res = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(res, tf.float32), 1)
       res = tf.where(tf.equal(res1, [0.0]))[0]

    with tf.Session(graph=g) as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    dict_ = {
        a:np.array([[2.0,6.0,3.0,2.0],
                   [1.0,8.0,32.0,1.0],
                   [1.0,8.0,3.0,11.0]]),
        b:np.array([[1.0,8.0,3.0,11.0]])
    }

    print(sess.run(res, feed_dict=dict_))
    :[2]
```