# Return the index where the Tensor is equal 0

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I have a tensor :

```
TensorShape([4, 3])


a=[[0,0,0][0,0,1][0,0,0][0,0,1]]
```

I need the index where it is equal for [0,0,0]

how can I do it ? In tensorflow 2.0

So i want the index 0 and 2 in this case.
indexes=[0,2]
Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this way (reference [Tensorflow : Get indices of array rows which are zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41806689/tensorflow-get-indices-of-array-rows-which-are-zero)):

```
x = tf.Variable([
[1,2,3,1],
[0,0,0,0],
[1,3,5,7],
[0,0,0,0],
[3,5,7,8]])

row_wise_sum = tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(x),1)
select_zero_sum = tf.where(tf.equal(row_wise_sum,0))
```

```py
with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    print(sess.run(select_zero_sum))
```

OUTPUT:

```
[[1]
[3]]
```